# How to resolve GC overhead in pyspark Databricks

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, garbage-collection, azure-databricks

I am trying to load a 100 gb json file in a spark dataframe and creating an temporary view over it. Then I am querying the data in this view with query

```
select * from <table_view> limit 1;
```

But The query doesn't get complete rather it gives Error `Caused by : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead limit exceeded.` I am running my code in databricks cluster. Here are my cluster details:

```
Cluster Mode : standard
Databricks runtime Version : 6.1(Apache Spark 2.4.4)
Worker Type : 56 GB Memory, 16 cores 3 DBU (min worker= 2, max worker = 8) 
Driver Type : 56 GB Memory, 16 cores 3 DBU
```

I tried setting the below config parameters but didn't get any success.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", '50g')
spark.conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '5')
spark.conf.set('spark.cores.max', '16')
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.memory",'30g')
spark.conf.set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead",4096)
```

I am very new to apache spark. Please let me know if some other details are required.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't have enough resources to load the entire file as a dataframe. I see two options.

1. Create a temporary dataframe by limiting number of rows after you read the json and create table view on this smaller dataframe. E.g. if you want to read only 1000 rows, do something like this: `small_df = entire_df.limit(1000)` and then create view on top of `small_df`.
2. You can increase the cluster resources. I've never used Databricks runtime, but you most likely need to increase number of worker nodes. I'd suggest going with more number of executors with lesser memory instead of very few bulky executors. This will give you more parallelism.

One more thing. By default spark uses 200 shuffle partitions. So, in your case each partition will contain roughly 0.5GB worth of data. It's probably a better idea to bring down that side by increasing number of partitions (e.g. 1000). It can be done by setting `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1000)`.